# calculating odds of a current passing in a circuit

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

would appreciate your help:

i have the following circuit [image]

eachone of the switches is closed in a probability of 0.7(and then the current is passing). each switch is independent of the other

and i need to calculate:

1)if switch 3 is open, what are the odds of a current passing from A to B?

2)if switch 3 is closed, what are the odds of a current passing from A to B?

my attempt:

1)if 3 is open, to pass current  we need 1 &2  or 4 & 5. so is it 0.7 * 0.7 + 0.7*0.7-0.24?

2)if 3 is closed, to pass a current we need (1 or 4) and (2 or 5) = (0.7+0.7-0.49)*(0.7+0.7-0.49)?

are my calculations correct? please correct me if i have done something wrong.

thank you very much!

Comment: First of all, you should specify that the switches are open or closed independently of one another.  Secondly (for the first question), you are double counting and should subtract the case when all four of $1,2,4,5$ are closed.  This double counting will come up again in the second question.

Comment: Note:  to see intuitively that your expression is incorrect, suppose each switch was closed with (independent) probability $.9$ instead of your $.7$  ...  then your expression would give the answer $.81+.81>1$ which is impossible.

Comment: @lulu i edited it and i understand what you're saying, but don't know how tocalculate it correctly. i should've spotted that i'mcounting twice because of the probability being >1

Comment: As I say, subtract the intersection (since you are counting it twice).  If a switch is closed with probability $p$ then you get $2p^2-p^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ is not correct because the chances of $1+2$ and $4+5$ are not disjoint.  If you change the chance a switch is closed to $0.8$ you will get a result greater than $1$.  Use $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$.  You missed the last term.

For $2)$ you should not consider the chance that $3$ is closed because you are given that.  You need $(1$ or $4)$ and $(2$ or $5)$

Comment: so for 1, should it be (1 and 2) or (4 and 5) = (0.7*0.7) or (0.7 *0.7) = 0.49 + 0.49 - 0.24? i think i still doing a mistake here

and for 2, should it be (1 or 4) and (2 or 5) = (0.7+0.7-0.49)*(0.7+0.7-0.49)?

Comment: That is correct except the $0.24$ should be $0.2401$ if you think the $0.7$ is exact.

Comment: the second one is also correct?

Comment: Yes it is........